# Proper way to check for particular .data() value in a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to check to see if a jQuery data value has been applied to an object. For instance, code elsewhere may assign data to an object:

```
$myObject.data('hello','world');
```

Elsewhere, I want to check to see if a value was given to the data property hello.

What is the proper way to handle this? `.hasData` seemed like the obvious choice but appears to not work like 'hasClass' does in that you can't seem to pass a particular data element name to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To obtain the property (e.g. for comparison), use `.data` with one argument:

```
$myObject.data('hello')
```

It returns the `undefined` value when the data does not exists.

Comment: so, would you use something like `if(typeof $myObject.data('hello')
 === "undefined"))`? That should work, but seems 'un-jQuery-ish' ;)

Comment: @DA. There's no "jQuery-ish" method for your request. You can write a plugin, if you wish. All you need is this information: 1. After assigning a value using `.data()`, the **DOM element** receives a property whose name is equal to `$.expando`. 2. This property, eg "jQuery1710979685063056744", holds an identifier. 3. This identifier, eg. "29" corresponds to a key in `$.cache`, eg. `$.cache[29]`. The data is stored in `$.cache[29].data`.

Answer (score 9):

Check if the data exists and set it if not.

```
if ($myObject.data('hello') === undefined) {
    // data NOT set
    $myObject.data('hello','world');
} else {
    // data IS set
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also try:

```
$myObject.hasData("hello")
```

It will return true if there is data, and false if there isn't anything. The link on the jQuery website: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.hasdata/

Comment: This is the most correct way to do this check per the jQuery website.  "The primary advantage of jQuery.hasData(element) is that it does not create and associate a data object with the element if none currently exists. In contrast, jQuery.data(element) always returns a data object to the caller, creating one if no data object previously existed."

Comment: @JamesWilson, it's entirely incorrect. This just checks whether there is data at all, and it is not a property of a jQuery object, but rather jQuery itself.

Comment: Does not work.  I get TypeError: $(...).hasData is not a function.